# Updating Object during isUpdate and isBefore trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, test-data-isolation, test-data

I have a trigger that fires on the event `trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore` for the `Account` object. In this trigger, I need to update a field in the `Account` object. I tried to add an `update` statement in the trigger, but then I get the error about not being able to use DML statements in `trigger.new` (which makes sense). Intuitively, it makes sense that I can just set the field value in my trigger, and then the update that fired the trigger in the first place will update whatever changes I made.

However, when I run my unit tests, the changes that I made in trigger don't show up. At this point, I don't know if it's an error with triggers or an error in my testing.

(Simplified) Code below:

Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTriggers on Account (before update, after update) {
   if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isBefore ) {
       AccountTriggerHelper.BeforeUpdateTriggers(trigger.new);
   }
}
```

Trigger Helper:

```
public class AccountTriggerHelper {
    public static void BeforeUpdateTriggers(List<Account> accounts) {
        UpdateProrations(accounts);
    }

    public static void UpdateProrations(List<Account> accounts) {
        for(Account acc: accounts) {
            List<Opportunity> opps = [select Id from Opportunity where AcccountId = :acc.Id];
            if(acc.Update_Proration__c == true) {
                // do some logic here
                if(opps.size() > 0) {
                    // Can't use update here since trigger is 
                    // running on the Account object
                    acc.Update_Proration__c = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
private class AccountTriggersTests {
    @testSetup private static void setup() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Update_Proration__c = true;
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert acc;
        // And a bunch of other setup too
    }

    @isTest static void TestProration() {
        Test.startTest();
        Account acc = [select Id, Name, Update_Proration__c from Account where Name = 'Test Account'];
        acc.Update_Proration__c = true;
        update acc; // I expect this to trigger and set the Update_Proration__c flag to be false
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(false, acc.Update_Proration__c); //FAILS
    }
}
```

As I said, I don't know if this an issue with how my trigger is set up or with how my test class/test data generation is set up. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Most of your assumptions are fundamentally correct: you may mutate objects in `Trigger.new` without performing DML, and your updates will be persisted transparently.

There appear to be two issues preventing your unit test class from behaving as expected.

1. Your test setup includes no Opportunities associated with the Account. `opps.size()` will then always be zero, so you'll never enter the code path where you update the value of that Boolean field.
2. Your test needs to re-query data to validate the outcome of your trigger. When you perform DML, your sObject instance is not updated with the values of any changed fields due to automation, *except* that the `Id` field is populated when you do an `insert`.

   To get back changed field values, you must perform a SOQL query: `acc = [SELECT Update_Proration__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id`. Then you'll be able to write an assertion against its new value.

Comment: This was perfect. I did create some test opps in the test setup, I just didn't put it here to prevent clutter. But I did not know that you had to requery in the unit test to see the changes. I just started migrating some business logic into Apex, so I'm pretty new. Thank you!